# Select2 not working while using jquery.steps

Tags: jquery-select2, conflict

select2 not working at all.
this is order of js file's in my code :

```
<script src="{{asset('css/template/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/select/select2.full.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('css/template/app-assets/js/scripts/forms/select/form-select2.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('css/template/app-assets/vendors/js/extensions/jquery.steps.js')}}"></script>
```

the selector is inside

```
<form action="" id="form" method="" class="icons-tab-steps checkout-tab-steps wizard-circle">
           
           
</form>
```

form like that.
*any alternative option for select2 is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. jQuery must come before select2 js.
2. You must init select2 for element you want to use it for.
   for example:

   $(element).select2();

Comment: thanks for response.
jQuery library must come first,it was my mistake.
thank u again.